# Making a function that can be used by multiple buttons

Tags: python, function, button, tkinter

Just wondering if there's anyway to make it so that this function can affect multiple widgets. What I want to happen is when I click a button, it will change from red to green using the function;

```
def colour_change():
   self.configure(bg="green")

button1 = Tk.Button(self, bg="red")
button1.pack()
button2 = Tk.Button(self, bg="red)
button2.pack()
```

So for example, when you press button 1 it should change from red to green. The same with button 2. I know that I can do this using separate functions, but is there anyway that I can do it in the same one?

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, your function need to identify which widget called it; one approach is to pass an argument that refers to the widget. In the following example, an index into a list that contains the widgets is passed when the command is called:

```
import tkinter as tk


def colour_change(which_button):
    if buttons[which_button]['fg'] == 'red':
        buttons[which_button].configure(fg="blue")
    else:
        buttons[which_button].configure(fg="red")

root = tk.Tk()

button1 = tk.Button(root, text='button 1', fg="red", command=lambda: colour_change(0))
button1.pack()
button2 = tk.Button(root, text='button 2', fg="red", command=lambda: colour_change(1))
button2.pack()

buttons = [button1, button2]

root.mainloop()
```